# Where is setting the params in this prop function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am checking this live demo to build a pagination component on ReactJs: https://codesandbox.io/s/l29rokm9rm?hidenavigation=1&view=preview&file=/src/App.js:2182-2216

My question is: Where and how is setting the params in this function?:

```
onPageChanged={this.onPageChanged}
```

That function get "data":

```
onPageChanged = data => {
```

I don't get where and how the App is passing "data" to Pagination component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `this.onPageChanged` is being passed as a reference to the child component and it been called from there, it is not being called from here(App Component it self) to pass arguments to it!

if you check the `Pagination` component in the example that you've been provided, you will see that its is being called from `gotoPage` method of the component like below on line 53:

```
this.setState({ currentPage }, () => onPageChanged(paginationData));
```

and you can see that the `data` value comes from there in here `onPageChanged(paginationData)`

basically in react you can pass any value as props to the child components and as much as functions are considered as value ( for example you can assign a function to a variable ) then you can pass it down **as a reference (consider it as a callback)** to be called from another place!

Comment: Thank you @a_m_dev for ur answer. Let me check it. Still not clear for me this way to set data.

Comment: its so simple!!! :)))), you just pass a function by its name to another component to use it over there!!!